# Default to 'More Options' in Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar

In Google Calendar, when creating an event, I always utilize the options under 'More Options' (creating an all day event, modifying notifications, etc). I know it's only an extra click away, but with how many events I create, it gets annoying. Is there a way to set it so that the new event pop up opens with 'More Options' already open?

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't look like a practical, detailed question. Please check out [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a way to change the default behavior of clicking the "Create" button.

However, if you use the keyboard shortcut - just hit the <kbd>C</kbd> key for (C)reate when you're on the calendar - it opens the full More Options event creation dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

In the calendar grid view you can double click the time you want the event to start. That opens the full-screen event creation view.